# If $\cos(A-B) = 1/2$ and $\sin(A+B) = 1/2$, find the smallest positive values of $A$ and $B$ and also their most general values

Tags: trigonometry

Question:

> $\cos(A-B)=\frac 12$ and $\sin(A+B)=\frac 12$, find:
>
> 1. The smallest positive values of $A$ and $B$ and
> 2. Their most general values.

I am stuck on this question despite my best efforts. The problem which obstructs is actually the $2^{nd}$ part of question which says **find the most general values**  and that is where I require assistance since the answer provided to me by the answer key is something like this but I could not get it myself:-

[image: Answer]

Comment: Simply use the formulae for the general solution of $\cos(x)=\cos(y)$ and $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A-B=2n\pi\pm\frac\pi3$

$A+B=m\pi+(-1)^m\frac\pi6$

Adding them

$2A=(2n+m)\pi\pm\frac\pi3+(-1)^n\frac\pi6$

So, $A=(n+\frac m2)\pi\pm\frac\pi6+(-1)^n\frac\pi{12}$

By subtracting the equations, you can get $B$

($m,n$ are integers)